# Hexproof and reflector mage

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My [Longtusk Cub](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLongtusk%20Cub%5d) is on the battlefield.
On my opponent's turn he brings in [Reflector Mage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bReflector%20Mage%5d), targeting my cub to return my cub to my hand.
I respond with [Blossoming Defense](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlossoming%20Defense%5d) to make my cub hexproof.
Does my cub remain on the battlefield or back in my hand?

Second question
It is my opponent's turn.
My [Bristling Hydra](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBristling%20Hydra%5d) is on the battlefield.
I spend energy to make the hydra hexproof and +1/+1.
My opponent casts reflector mage, targeting the hydra.
Does the hydra remain on the board?

I would say cub stays and hydra goes to hand.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think we already covered the interactions here in the deadlock trap question. If there's some reason you're not sure what goes on here, can you elaborate on what about the situation strikes you as different?

Comment: @doppelgreener The second question I don't think it is a duplicate, but it could use some clarifications like was the Mage given flash somehow, or did the Hydra's ability resolve.

Answer (score 1):

> Does my cub remain on the battlefield or back in my hand?

It remains on the battlefield. Reflector Mage's ability does target ("When Reflector Mage enters the battlefield, return target creature an opponent controls to its owner's hand.[...]"), and Hexproof makes that an invalid target:

> CR 702.11b “Hexproof” on a permanent means “This permanent can’t be the target of spells or abilities your opponents control.”

The Reflector Mage, and its triggered ability, are both controlled by your opponent, so the target is illegal. Since the ability has all illegal targets, it is countered upon resolution, and none of its effects happen.

> My Bristling Hydra is on the battlefield. I spend energy to make the hydra hexproof and +1/+1. My opponent casts Reflector Mage, targeting the hydra.

This cannot happen as described. If you have activated, and resolved, the hydra's ability, it cannot be chosen as a target for Reflector Mage's ability.

That being said, if Reflector Mage is entering the battlefield *in response* to your hydra's activated ability (perhaps your opponent cast Collected Company in response, and found a Reflector Mage), then **yes**, it can be chosen as a target. Unless you choose to respond to the targeting by activating the ability a second time, then the hydra will return to your hand.